# Sum by criteria after merging by another criteria VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project to merge and sum cells by different sets of criteria. The raw data contains category A, B, and C; each of them contain subcategories (dynamic) ranging from a to j. It is not necessary to have all subcategories presented under a category.

[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q74RE.png)

I would need to conduct the merging and calculation by such orders:

1. Under bigger categories A, B, and C, merge the cells for each categories in column 4 "Aggregate" (Succeeded);

[Merged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm0dq.png)

2. To sum and d, e, and h and return the result if they presented under each category. For example, if under A, d and e are presented as 4 and 5, then the big merged cell corresponding to A should show 4+5=9; if under B, h, d, e are presented as 8,9,10, then the corresponding merged cell should be 8+9+10=27. The effect is as shown.

[Final Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFSqB.png)

I have the code written, however it returns mismatch when going into the calculation. It is as below:

```
Sub shishi()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim row As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

lr = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

MergeCells:

    For Each rng In Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(lr, 4))
    
        If rng.Offset(0, -3).Value = _
        rng.Offset(1, -3).Value And _
        rng.Offset(0, -3).Value <> "" Then
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
                
        GoTo MergeCells
        End If
        
    Next
    
    For Each rng2 In Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lr, 2))
    
        If rng2.Value = "d" Or "e" _
            Or "h" And _
            rng2.Offset(0, -1).Value = _
            rng2.Offset(1, -1).Value Then
            
            Sum = Sum + rng2.Offset(0, 1).Value
            rng2.Value = Sum
            Else
            Sum = 0
        End If
    Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Any thought or direction would be sincerely appreciated! Thank you all up front!

Edited 15:50 PM 09/10/2020:
After BigBen's hint the code nearly works perfectly, and an issue occurred when I implemented it to the original big data set. The issue of merging came out that only the upper left number was kept - which is exactly not what I want, so I swapped the order of calculation/merging and added a function to swap the number in the later merging stage.

And after fixing another logic about if current row's category <> next row's category the row will be skipped, I made it check the row above to identify if the value are identical.

I ran into a new problem that between B and C category, the subcategory e is the same, while my logic is supposedly picking out the inequality and reset the sum count, it did not...And brought the sum from B straight into the calculation of C.

Here is the current setup of raw data and the code:

[Raw Data V.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvgIt.png)

I updated some values to create a more direct case in presenting numeric differences (and more obvious indications for miscalculation by the code).

```
Sub shishi()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim row As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim temp As Long

lr = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    
    For Each rng2 In Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lr, 2))
    
        If rng2.Value = "d" Or _
            rng2.Value = "e" Or _
            rng2.Value = "h" And _
            rng2.Offset(0, -1).Value = _
            rng2.Offset(-1, -1).Value Then
            
            Sum = Sum + rng2.Offset(0, 1).Value
            rng2.Offset(0, 2).Value = Sum
            Else
            Sum = 0
        End If
    Next
    
MergeCells:

    For Each rng In Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(lr, 4))
    
        If rng.Offset(0, -3).Value = _
        rng.Offset(1, -3).Value And _
        rng.Offset(0, -3).Value <> "" Then
        
            If rng.Offset(1, 0).Value > rng.Value Then
            temp = rng.Offset(1, 0).Value
            rng.Value = temp
            End If
            
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
        
        GoTo MergeCells
        End If
        
    Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

That is also the only problem left - I have all the rest of codes running exactly as expected. Thanks a lot again!

Edit: 16:55 PM 09/10/2020

The code is in fact more broken than I thought...I would like to gather any suggestion to make the logic right. Please disregard what I commented about the code as it is nearly working. Thanks...

Comment: `rng2.Value = "d" Or "e" _
            Or "h" And` doesn't work. You have to repeat the left side of the comparison... `If rng2.Value = "d" Or rng2.Value = "e" Or rng2.Value = "h"`

Comment: Thank you @BigBen! I have accepted the great answers!

Comment: Don't show images of data, show [formated text](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (data, expected result, actual result as code)

Comment: Hi @ComputerVersteher I am working on correcting the numbers for formated text. Thank you!